# Writing "code" extension in Jinja2

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I am trying to write an extension for Jinja2 so that I can run arbitrary python code in my templates (I have a sandbox to run this code safely). I know I can use something like Mako which allows embedding python code but I prefer using Jinja2 as I like it's syntax in general.

An example of what I intend to do in the template:

```
{{ x }}

{% code %}
x = x + 1
{% endcode %}

{{ x }}
```

If I render above template with x = 1, I expect the output to be,

```
1
2
```

I wrote an extension based on the example on the docs. I am able to access the context by using the contextfunction decorator but it is immutable.

Inside my callback in the extension, I would like to do something like this

```
exec body in context
```

Can some Jinja2 guru help me out here?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need, but try implementing the [filter_stream](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/extensions/#jinja2.ext.Extension.filter_stream) method.